# How do I check to see if a form field contains a specific word or phrase?

Tags: php, forms, validation

I am creating a PHP form, and came across another issue. Unlike the others, this one I cannot figure out (And Google is not helping).

I have an HTML form with PHP validation, and one of the fields is a URL field. I want the input within that field to be formatted a specific way. I will put examples of what is valid/not valid, as well as the code below.

**ALLOWED INPUT** - Basically anything that includes "thisismydomain.com"

> https://www.thisismydomain.com
> [www.thisismydomain.com](http://www.thisismydomain.com)
> thisismydomain.com
> https://thisismydomain.com
> *Any of the above + directories are allowed, such as adding /anythingathere to any of the above*

**INVALID INPUT**

> https://www.notmydomain.com
> [www.notmydomain.com](http://www.notmydomain.com)
> notdomain.com
> https://notmydomain.com

The form field: (Yes, that does say "vurl". I found that if it says "url", the browser requires a "http://" or "https://" to submit)

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="form-label" for="vurl">URL</label>
            <p>Please provide the URL of the page with the error</p>
            <input type="vurl" name="vurl" id="subject" class="form-feild" size="40">
        </div>
```

The Submission Rule: (It don't work at the moment, this is what I need help with. Only the first line does not work, the second line has been tested with other submission rules and it works.)

```
if (strpos($_POST['vurl'], 'thisismydomain.com"') !== false) {
    redirectWithError("Please enter a valid URL");
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a made up type like `vurl`, use `text`. Regarding your issue, your logic is backwards. You should redirect with error if the string does _not_ exist, which means: `if (strpos(...) === false)`. If `strpos()` returns anything other than `false`, it means that the string _does_ exist. However, if you want the string to be in a specific format, you should probably use regex instead since your current check would allow any string that contains `thisismydomain.com`, regardless of format.

Comment: Could you add that as an answer, but also include how I would do this regex thing? I have no clue what it is. Thanks

Comment: I've actually voted to close this as a typo, since [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) clearly shows how to use the `strpos()` function. And regarding the regex, you need to do some research into that one and make some attempts. I don't have the exact regex in my head right now.

Comment: use parse_url, its trivial to make sure it contains at least http:// at the front, it validates the URL and can return the hostname in one shot, else `notthisismydomain.com` would pass your check